# C++ create a char* iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, char, std

I like to write container agnostic code that uses `std` methods like `std::distance()` or `std::advance()` in my code. This is useful for deserialization where I can pass in buffer objects of different types (network stream, byte stream, ...).

How can I convert `char*` or `uint8_t*` pointers to an iterator? Copying the data to a buffer is not an option.

One option I have in mind is to use a custom allocator with `std::string` but I'd prefer a more ready made solution if available.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Pointers *are* iterators - the most general ones even, *random access*.

Comment: Pointers are iterators. Just take care to handle `end()` correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several types of iterators, specified by what properties they have (functionality they support) - there is a nice overview here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/

Random access iterators require to implement all the iterator functionality seen in that table.

Raw pointers do in fact support all the operations and are therefore random access <strike>operators</strike> iterators and can be used for all STL algorithms and containers. Also discussed here [Can raw pointers be used instead of iterators with STL algorithms for containers with linear storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445957/can-raw-pointers-be-used-instead-of-iterators-with-stl-algorithms-for-containers).

Although not necessary, it might still be useful to implement an iterator wrapper for your pointers - this is also discussed in the answers to the question above.

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)'s iterator page may also be useful.  Less friendly, but tends to be more reliable.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind. Those pointers work as iterators anyway because they implement the basic functionality.