# Can C++ array end at memory boundary?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, c++11

C++ standard (and C for that matter) allows to create (not dereference though) a pointer to one element past the end of the array. Does this mean that an array will never be allocated at such a location that its last element ends at the memory boundary? I understand that in practice some/all implementation might follow this convention, but which one the following is true:

1. It's actually false, and an array might end at memory boundary, OR
2. It is mandated by C++ standard to end at least one element's worth of memory before the boundary, OR
3. Neither 1, nor 2, but it is still like that in actual compilers because it makes  implementation easier.

Is anything different for the case of C?

**Update:**
It seems like **1** is the correct answer. See answer from James Kanze below, and also see `efence` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/efence - thanks to Michael Chastain for the pointer to it)

Comment: I don't think the standard, certainly for C++ mandates anything about memory allocation wrt to this so 1 and 2 would not be true and probably 3 is more likely an implementation detail

Comment: Trying to find a stuiable reference here, for c++ and c there is a line halfway down this page on [sutter's site](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill14.htm) `The C++ standard guarantees that all memory allocated via operator new or malloc will be suitably aligned for any possible kind of object you might want to store in it, which means that operator new and malloc have to respect the strictest possible type alignment requirement of the native platform` this doesn't mention anything about memory boundaries though

Comment: I should clarify my first comment, for 1 it might end at a memory boundary but this is not something that is specified in the standard and would be up to the implementor

Comment: I don't think in practice this is a concern. You'd need to have a platform whose (virtual) memory size is the same as (or exceeds) the maximum representable memory address by the native pointer type.

Comment: @EdChum: Regarding the alignment quote from Herb's website: I think it is about adhering to the memory alignment requirement various platforms put on individual data types (and not to this specific question). For example, malloc on GNU systems always return memory block starting at 8 or 16 bytes (Ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html). These particular values are of course implementation specific to glibc (C++ only guarantees that memory from malloc/new will be suitable for storing any datatype on the platform)

Comment: Yes I agree, I can't seem to find anything that mandates this requirement and it appears so far that this will be implementation specific

Comment: @SanderDeDycker The virtual memory size is irrelevant.  What's relevant is what has been mapped to the process.  The address `0x40000000` may point to one past the end of an array, even if the system has only mapped the first GB.  The question is whether this is legal.

Comment: @JamesKanze : my point was that 0x40000000 can be stored into a 32-bit pointer variable, whereas 0x100000000 couldn't. So, having a pointer one past the end of the array can be trivially made to work, except if that pointer would overflow the pointer type. And that could only happen if the addressable range meets or exceeds the range of the pointer type. I can't think of a platform where that's true. Obviously, trap conditions can exist (like you point out in your answer), but those can be worked around.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker It can always be made to work; just don't use the last byte/word of the allocated block.  As for machines where the addressable range exceeds the range of the pointer type: there's Intel, if your pointers don't include the segment register.

Comment: A pointer can be set to point to both valid and invalid memory addresses, so an array can be allocated at such a location that its last element ends at the memory boundary. As you've mentioned yourself, if a pointer points to an invalid memory address, then it cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: @JamesKanze : point well taken - guess I'm showing my youth by not considering the olden days (and maybe still some embedded platforms) where memory was scarce and pointer types were tiny. I retract my earlier statements :)

Comment: @barakmanos: Actually that's incorrect. According to C & C++ standards, the mere act of storing an "illegal" memory address is *Undefined behavior* (see James Kanze's answer below, and also Point 3 here:  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/iterators.html)

Comment: @abi: I prefer to think of pointers as pointing to spaces "between" memory locations, and saying that "`*foo`" means "the thing immediately following the place `foo` points".  A 12" ruler has thirteen markings at 0", 1", 2", up to 12", and has 12 spaces between markings; each of the twelve inches has a mark at the beginning and a mark at the end.  Under such a viewpoint, the 12" mark is simply a mark like any other, even though nothing follows it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

An implementation must allow a pointer to one past the end to
exist.  How it does this is its business.  On many machines, you
can safely put any value into a pointer, without risk (unless
you dereference it); on such systems, the one past the end
pointer may point to unmapped memory—I've
actually encountered a case under Windows where it did.

On other machines, just loading a pointer to unmapped memory
into a register will trap, causing the program to crash.  On
such machines, the implementation must ensure that this doesn't
happen, either by refusing to use the last byte or word of
allocated memory, or by ensuring that all use of the pointer
other than dereferencing it avoids any instructions which might
cause the hardware to treat it as an invalid pointer.  (Most such
systems have separate address and data registers, and will only
trap if the pointer is loaded into an address register.  If the
data registers are large enough, the compiler can safely load
the pointer into a data register for e.g. comparison.  This is
often necessary anyway, as the address registers don't always
support comparison.)

Re your last question: C and C++ are exactly identical in this respect; C++ simply took over the rules from C.

Comment: This is very informative. And quite crazy/scary. I never would reasonably excpect that I am not allowed to manipulate pointers to wherever the f** I please. This actually kindof invalidates things I have implemented in the past (end iterator pointing to unmapped memory). Are such systems usually paged (therefore reducing the chance of trapping due to large chunks of memory getting mapped) ?

Comment: @v.oddou There are a lot of machines where this is the case.  Starting with Intel architecture, if you use the segment registers.  (Loading an invalid segment into a segment register will trap.  Most compilers today don't support it, but I've worked on Intel with 48 bit pointers, and just reading a random pointer value could trap.)

Comment: @v.oddou Or as I once saw written in the early days of C: "Ah, for the good old days, when men were men, women were women, and pointers were ints."  It seems like we've come the full circle, and that once again, most people today think that pointers must map to some integral type.  (Back in the days when I was learning C, the machines I worked on were mostly 16 bit, but we had far more than 64K memory.  And all sorts of "structured" pointers to address it.  And then, there were the 36 bit word addressed machine, in which the byte address and size of a `char*` were in the high order bits.)

Comment: @v.oddou You're just too young:-).  In primitive computers, the address was just another machine word (which usually addressed other words---there weren't any bytes).  As memory grew, and computers otherwise became smaller (16 bits, rather than 36, 48 or 60), more complicated schemas evolved (whence the quote, doubtlessly from someone who knew the primitive systems).  Today, when 32 bit systems are more or less a minimum, and 64 bit systems common, we've returned to the pointers are ints situation.  For most people; as I said, I've worked on 32 bit Intel with 48 bit pointers.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, but could you back up your reasoning with relevant sections of the C++ standard?

Comment: @psyill §5.7/5: "[...] Moreover, if the expression P points to
the last element of an array object, the expression (P)+1 points
one past the last element of the array object[...]".  (I'm not
sure exactly what points you want me to back up, but the above
makes it clear that a pointer one past the end of an array is
legal, even if you cannot dereference it.)

Comment: Thanks, sorry that I did not specify earlier what parts of your reasoning I did not follow: I'm curious about the "[a]n implementation must allow a pointer to one past the end to exist" part, when considering that a pointer value not representing "the address of a byte in memory" or a null pointer is invalid.

Comment: Yep, this "loophole" of sorts exists so that one can write a loop along the lines of `while (*somePtr++)` and have it not take an exception when `somePtr` is incremented the very last time.  It does not imply that the final value of `somePtr` must be at all valid, just that the increment operation must not cause an exception/trap.

Comment: @psyill Then this quote covers it.  It's a pretty standard idiom: in modern C++ `for ( p = std::begin(a); p != std::end(a); ++ p )` will leave `p` pointing to one past the end.

Comment: I just found out (courtesy Michael Chastain) about `efence` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/efence). So not only an array can be allocated at the end of the memory boundary, it is actively used in creative ways by tools like `efence`.

Comment: @James Kanze Disagree about " Today, when 32 bit systems are more or less a minimum".  With embedded processors, at least 100s of million per year in 2014 use 16-bit `int` and C is very popular there.  Do not have numbers about all processors made in 2013, but I would not be surprised if most processors today are sub 32-bit.

Comment: The pointer past the last element of an array must not only exist, it also must follow some rules. If p points to the last element of an array, and q = p + 1, then it is required that q > p, q - p = 1, p - q = -1. That was a problem with segmented memory (pointer = segment + 16 bit offset); if p was at offset 0xffff, and q = p + 1 was at offset 0xffff + 1 = 0x0, then q > p wasn't true so the last byte of a segment couldn't be part of the array.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Am I the only person who thinks that the 8086 addressing scheme was brilliant, but 80286 dropped the ball and the 80386 failed to fix it?  If segments on the 80386 had been 32-bit values that combined a 4-bit selector with a 28-bit scaled offset, and the scaling factor was determined by a segment descriptor, then 32-bit object references could easily access many gigs of memory (each object would start at address zero of some segment).

Comment: @chux Yes.  I should have been more specific; I was talking about general purpose systems, which seemed to be implied by the question (memory boundary implies virtual memory?).

Comment: @supercat Pre-80286, the scaling factor was hard wired; there was no segment descriptor.  I think that the way Intel implemented segments starting with the 80286 _was_ very good; it supported all sorts of protection schemes.  But it came at a significant run-time cost---a segment descriptor was large (several words), and had to be loaded each time you loaded the segment.  So people tended to avoid it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The genius of the 8086 is that the only cost for each segment was the alignment requirement.  Given that even without such a requirement many memory management schemes padded things out to eight bytes anyway, and that every "segment-only" reference would save two bytes compared to a full pointer, I'd say the segments were very good from a storage perspective in code that could use them effectively (which, alas, languages couldn't).  There were some instruction-set weaknesses (notably, the fact that there were only two seg registers) but generally a good design.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The problem with the 80286 segments is that in order for them to be practical it was necessary to store many objects into each one, but since they were limited to 64K an application would typically have to use multiple segments to handle many kinds of objects.  If the 80286 had interpreted a 16-bit segment value as a 4-bit segment selector and a 12-bit scaled pre-offset value (whose scale factor was controlled by the selector) that would probably have been as good a design as could be achieved in a 16-bit machine.  If the 80386 had split segment registers as 8+24...

Comment: ...that would have allowed programs which didn't need more than a billion or so distinct objects to access multiple terabytes of memory efficiently while using 32-bit object references.  Given that 64-bit object references can only be cached half as efficiently as 32-bit ones, I would think that would have been better than using 64 bits for everything.

Comment: @supercat The design philosophy of the '286 was that each object would be in a separate segment, and calls to member functions would go through a call gate, which would load the segment and change the authorizations.  The idea was great; lot's of hardware protection, etc.  The problem was the run-time cost that this entailed.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Not only was it a huge run-time cost, but it also imposed a huge per-object memory overhead and an excessively-low limit on the number of discrete objects that could be allocated (16,384).  The 80386 reduced the effective cost by adding FS and GS, but failed to boost the 16,384-item limit which would have been confining even in a system with only 16 megabytes.  Care to chat?

Answer (score 6):

There's an interesting passage at §3.9.2/3 [Compound types]:

> The type of a pointer to void or a pointer to an object type is called an object pointer type. [...] A valid value of an object pointer type represents either the address of a byte in memory (1.7) or a null pointer (4.10).

Together with the text at §5.7/5 [Additive operators]:

> [...] Moreover, if the expression P points to the last element of an array object,
>   the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object, and if the expression Q points
>   one past the last element of an array object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
>   object.

it seems that an array ending at the last byte in memory can not be allocated, if there is a requirement that the one-past-the-end pointer must be valid. If the one-past-the-end pointer is allowed to be invalid, I don't know the answer.

The section §3.7.4.2/4 [Deallocation functions] states that:

> The effect of using an invalid pointer value
>   (including passing it to a deallocation function) is undefined.

Thus if comparing a one-past-the-end pointer for an allocated array must be supported, the one-past-the-end pointer must be valid.

Based on the comments I got, I assume that an implementation can allocate an array without having to care about if the array's one-past-the-end pointer is usable or not. However I would like to find out the relevant passages in the standard for this.

Comment: Your quote of `5.7/5` does not say that the one-past-the-end pointer needs to be valid.

Comment: No, it does not do so explicitly. I'm trying to figure out if there is some other part of the standard which put a requirement on the ability to use a one-past-the-end pointer.

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong (and I've actually seen a case once where the end of the array was at the absolute end of the allocated block).  All that is required is that the operations (other than dereferencing) on such a pointer work.  Which they will in most current environments.

Comment: That means that there's nothing in the standard requiring the ability of using each possible one-past-the-end pointer then?

Comment: @Kanze: Sorry for bothering you, but what do you mean by "[a]ll that is required is that the operations (other than dereferencing) on such a pointer work"? What's the definition of "work"?

Comment: @psyill: Meet the requirements of functionality laid out in the standard. Causing a hardware exception or crashing your computer do not count.

Comment: The snippet `foo* end = myarray+ arraylen; for (foo* p = myarray; p != end; p++)` works even if `myarray+arraylen` evaluates to `NULL` (or `(foo*)0`). You just shouldn't use  `p<end` instead.

Comment: I don't think the pointer past the last array element is allowed to be equal to NULL.

Answer (score 4):

You're half right. Suppose a hypothetical implementation uses linearly addressed memory and pointers that are represented as 16-bit unsigned integers. Suppose also that the null pointer is represented as zero. And finally, suppose you ask to for 16 bytes of memory, with `char *p = malloc(16);`. Then it's guaranteed that you will get a pointer of which the numeric value is less than 65520. The value 65520 itself wouldn't be valid, because as you rightly point out, assuming the allocation succeeded, `p + 16` is a valid pointer that must not be a null pointer.

However, suppose now that a hypothetical implementation uses linearly addressed memory and pointers that are represented as 32-bit unsigned integers, but only has an address space of 16 bits. Suppose also again that the null pointer is represented as zero. And finally, suppose again that you ask for 16 bytes of memory, with `char *p = malloc(16);`. Then it's only guaranteed that you will get a pointer of which the numeric value is less than or equal to 65520. The value 65520 itself would be valid, so long as the implementation makes sure that adding 16 to that gives you the value 65536, and that subtracting 16 gets you back to 65520. This is valid even if no memory (physical or virtual) exists at all at address 65536.

Comment: I like the hypotethical consideration that a block of memory could be returned so high that the `end` pointer would overflow and wrap.

Answer (score 3):

The standard states explicitly what happens when you increment the pointer to the last element. It gives you a value that can only be used as comparison to check if you're at or before the end of the array or not. The pointer may well point to validly allocated memory for some other object, but that is complete undefined (implementation defined?) behaviour and using that pointer as such is definitely undefined behaviour.

What I'm getting at is that the one-past-the-end pointer is just that: it is the pointer you get when you increment the pointer to the last element, to mark the end of the array in a very cheap way. But do note that comparing pointers of unrelated objects is completely nonsensical (and even undefined behaviour if I'm not mistaken). So the fact that there might be overlap in pointer "values" across different objects is a non-issue, as in exploiting this you enter the Land of Undefined Behaviour..

Comment: The first paragraph is completely false.  If you increment a null pointer, you have undefined behavior.  Some implementations allow just about anything in a pointer, others don't.

Comment: @rubenvb: I think you missed the fact that there is the notion of a "safely-derived" pointer.

Comment: @James Is this explanation better?

Comment: It's slightly misleading. "compare if you're at the end or not" suggests it only allows `operator==`, but `operator<` is also OK. you can check if a pointer is before the end. A compiler is allowed to optimize `operatoar<` to `operator !=` in this case!

Answer (score -2):

This depends on implementation. At least in visual C++ without using any from of array bound checking,  you could create a pointer any number of elements past the end of the array. If you dereference it it will still work as long as the memory address that you are accessing is within the allocated heap/stack of your program. You will read/modify whatever the value in that memory location. If the address is outside the allocated memory space it will give an error.

Debuggers has checks to detect these, as this kind of coding create bugs very difficult to track.

Comment: The question is not about VC++, but about what the standard mandates.

Comment: `you could create a pointer any number of elements past the end of the array` VC++ may allow UBs (and "work") but that doesn't answer the question.